# How to programmatically create a Subscription Add-On on Microsoft Store via API

Tags: api, uwp, windows-store-apps, windows-10-universal, windows-store

I need to create some Add-Ons of type "Subscription" for my UWP product in the Microsoft Store.
I have seen several API that are used to manage the subscription (e.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/change-the-billing-state-of-a-subscription-for-a-user and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/get-subscriptions-for-a-user) but nothing so far to create a new subscription.

Moreover, there is an API to create Add-Ons, but only for types "Durable" and "Consumable" (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/create-an-add-on).

Are you aware of any API to create a Subscription?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is no API that could create subscription Add-ons based on the document. You have to create it on the Partner Center now. You could submit a feature request on the Feedback Hub about this.